# Questions on GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

I am trying to use GeoGraphics for some land navigation. In the spirit of showing my work, here is what I've done so far:

```
battleAx = GeoBoundsRegion[{{44.5, 45.75}, {-123., -122}}];

colWay = GeoPosition[{45.61996, -122.66791}];

home = GeoPosition[{45.6138, -122.5837}];

homeMarker = GeoCircle[home, 500];

colWayMarker = GeoCircle[colWay, 500];

reliefMap = 
 GeoGraphics[{battleAx, Red, homeMarker, colWayMarker}, 
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoScaleBar -> "Imperial", 
  GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Graphics]

The graphic produced by GeoGraphics of a region always seems to designate the region by darkening it and making it less readable. Is there a way to eliminate that?

Comment: You may just mean to do `GeoRange -> battleAx` a rather than including it in the items to be drawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `FaceForm[]` or `GeoStyling[Opacity[0]]` or `GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]` before `battleAx`:

```
{rm1, rm2, rm3} = GeoGraphics[{#, battleAx, Red, homeMarker, colWayMarker}, 
     GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoScaleBar -> "Imperial", 
     GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap", ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  {FaceForm[], GeoStyling[Opacity[0]], GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]};

Row[{rm1, rm2, rm3}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- perfect!